# How do you kill all mobs after you die?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I'm making an adventure map and doing a dungeon style thing. After you die in the "dungeon", I want all mobs in that specific area to die so the player can try again.

I've tried doing a `testfor` command but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How about just when they respawn, there's a pressure plate or command block to check if player's nearby, then kill all mobs?

Comment: Reason for voting to reopen: All answers on that other question use `/testfor`, which no longer exists.

Comment: It would be better to have a new question that addresses the removal of `/testfor`.  This question is still a duplicate for a version that did have that command working still, thus people searching for 1.8 that find this question would be lead back to the correct answer.

Comment: Questions with outdated answers do not cease to be valid duplicate targets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You first have to create a scoreboard like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

Then you put a repeating, always active command block somewhere out of sight (but still in the loaded area), containing this command:

```
/execute at @a[scores={deaths=1..}] run kill @e[type=!player,distance=..10]
```

And in the direction the repeating command block is facing put an always active chain command block (can be conditional if you make it face the same way) containing this command:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[scores={deaths=1..}] deaths 0
```

This kills all entities except for players in a radius of 10 around the dead player.

Comment: Would that be in the area they would respawn or in the area where the mobs were?

Comment: It's at the death location. The player location is set to the respawn location as soon as they click "respawn", but since this runs 0,05s after the death, the player probably didn't click that yet, especially because the buttons need a bit of time to become clickable.

Comment: Did you already publish the map and link to this question? I'm getting an unusual amount of upvotes. It's my second most upvoted answer on this site (5th most upvoted post overall) and that in just 5 hours.

Comment: Now it's the most upvoted on this site (with two others) and only one answer on another site had more upvotes than this. The other answer here that got the same amount of upvotes took 3 weeks for that, this one 6 hours. Wow.

Comment: @Fabian this question got into Hot Network Questions (HNQ) bar which is shown on the right side on all SE sites. It means more exposure and more upvotes (due to association bonus rep).

Comment: Ah, that explains it, thanks! If you're interested to read stuff, there's more answers by me, multiple of them I would call better than this one. ;)

Comment: Why have you used `@a` then `@e`? You should be consistent.

Comment: That's not a point of consistency, it's a point of actually working. @a selects all players, @e selects all entities. It's intended how it is.

Comment: The point was that you use `@e` in the second `scoreboard` command, where it doesn't make sense for non-player entities.

Comment: I don't see your problem. At first I use `@a`, because I want to select all players. That's what `@a` does. Then I want to select everything that is not a player, so I can't use `@a` and have to use `@e`. Sure, I could replace `@a` with `@e[type=player]`, but why would I? There is a selector just for players, so I use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scoreboard` objectives...

`/scoreboard objectives add youDied deathCount`
The `deathCount` will automatically increase when someone dies.

Now you can run a clock to test for it:
`/testfor @a[score_youDied_min=1]`
(1 = one death, you could as well use a higher number to grant them multiple lives before it resets)

The command to kill the mobs is `/kill @e[x,y,z,r,type=!Player]` and don't forget to reset the death count:
`/scoreboard players set @a youDied 0`

Comment: He wants to kill all entities **in an area**, so you have to use `execute` instead of `testfor`.

Comment: @Fabian yep I forgot about the kill radius, but wouldn't `/kill @e[x,y,z,r,type=!Player]`work as well?

Comment: Only if you knew the coordinates of the player before writing that command.

Comment: probably in the dungeon, which is known :P (radius can be applied as well)

Comment: Ok, but it's still more effort and one command block more. If you want fixed coordinates, you can just use `execute @a[score_deaths_min=1] 12 34 56 <command>`.